# 2's complement of a 16 bit number

Tags: c

```
UInt16 Checksum16Calculate(CHECKSUM_16_TYPE* pChecksum)
{
//calculate twos compliment of checksum
pChecksum->usTwosCompliment = ~(pChecksum->usChecksum) + 1;

//store raw checksum for diagnostics
pChecksum->uiChecksumWatch = pChecksum->usChecksum;

return pChecksum->usTwosCompliment;
}



typedef struct
{
UInt16 usChecksum;
UInt16 usWordCount;
UInt16 usTwosCompliment;
UInt32 uiChecksumWatch;
}
CHECKSUM_16_TYPE;
```

I call CheckSumCalculate with &oChecksum which is of type CHECKSUM_16_TYPE.  Lets say the number before calculating the checksum is 10010101110.  Taking its twos complement by hand gives you 1101010010.  However the number i get back is **111110** 1101010010.  Ignoring the bolded numbers I would have correct answer.  I think this is happening because the number im taking the 2's complement of is a 16 bit number so it switches the unused 0's to 1's.  What would i do to fix this?

Comment: There's no such thing as "unused bits". If you want a 10 bit complement you'll have to generate a 16 bit complement and mask off the bits you need.

Comment: What @Mark said, or alternatively: why do you believe your checksum *should be* only 10 digits long? After all, it bears the name "CHECKSUM_16_TYPE", which is then a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C Standard

> 4 The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its
>   (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only
>   if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). **The
>   integer promotions are performed on the operand,** and the result has
>   the **promoted type**. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the
>   expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that
>   type minus E.

So operand of `operator ~`

```
~(pChecksum->usChecksum)
```

is promoted to type `int` and you have

```
0000010010101110 <= original value of type `UInt16`
00000000000000000000010010101110 <= promoted value of type `int`
11111111111111111111101101010001 <= applying operator ~
11111111111111111111101101010010 <= adding 1
1111101101010010 <= assigning back the resul to the object of type `UInt16`
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  My goal is to have the opposite of the number, then add them together after reading the data back and if all goes good should = 0.  How would I 'get rid' of the bits i dont want each time i need to generate a checksum for a log entry?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing to fix. The number `10010101110` is represented as a 16-bit binary number as `0000010010101110`; its 2's complement can only be `1111101010001010`.